# When function A calls function B that calls function C. And how to handle multiple Nones

Tags: python

Here is an example:

```
def getNumber3(arg):
    if arg!=7:
        print 'arg!=7'
        return
    return 7

def getNumber5(arg):
    if arg!=5:
        print 'getNumber5(): arg!=5'
        return

    number7=getNumber3(7)
    if not number7:
        print 'getNumber5(): not number7'
        return
    return '%s-%s'%(arg,number7)

def getNumber():
    number5=getNumber5(5)
    if number5:
        return 'The number is: %s'%number5

print getNumber()
```

Function `getNumber5()` is expecting a return value from `getNumber3()` which will return `None` and print an "Error" message if the incoming argument number is not 7.

Function `getNumber5()` if it receives `None` (from function `getNumber3`) will complain and return 'None' too.

As a result the both functions: `getNumber5()` and `getNumber3()` are complaining and returning `None`.

Question: How should this functions workflow arranged so the very first function `getNumber` (that starts it all) gets None as soon as 'getNumber3()' function returns None bypassing `getNumber5()'. So`getNumber5()' function doesn't have to complain and return its own None.

Comment: I appreciate how straightforward and easy to follow this example is.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I'm looking at the program flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use exception handling to immediately jump back to `getNumber()`.

```
class NoNumberException(Exception):
    pass

def getNumber3(arg):
    if arg!=7:
        print 'arg!=7'
        raise NoNumberException
    return 7

def getNumber5(arg):
    if arg!=5:
        print 'getNumber5(): arg!=5'
        return

    number7=getNumber3(7)
    if not number7:
        print 'getNumber5(): not number7'
        return
    return '%s-%s'%(arg,number7)

def getNumber():
    try:
        number5=getNumber5(5)
        if number5:
            return 'The number is: %s'%number5
    except NoNumberException:
        return "None value encountered in getNumber3()"

print getNumber()
```

Comment: +1 This is exactly what exceptions are for: to separate error reporting from returned values.

Comment: Cool! Great to know. I always thought Exceptions will always stop a code from execution and print an Error message like in a horror movie. Thanks again! It turns they (Exceptions) much less violent!

Comment: I would have to use `try: except:` to make sure the code is still running after the Exception is raised. Correct? Since it seems raising the Exception outside `try: except:` stops the program...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Any uncaught exceptions will end your program right away, but if it's an error mentioned in `except`, you'll move on to the bit of code listed there. That's another important point - if any other exception besides `NoNumberException` were raised in that `try/except` block, your program would stop immediately.